# Do I Need To Get Latest Before Pushing To The Remote Server

Tags: git

Using Git.

All this is being done in Visual Studio 2017.

OK, so I get the latest from remote master using pull. Then I make a local branch and do my coding.

Meanwhile, the other developers are committing code the remote master.

Many days later, I commit my changes to my local branch.

What do I do next?

Do I get the latest to master using pull?

Do I then merge my branch into master locally? How?

I am told I then push my branch to the server and a copy of it is created there, then there is a pull request and when the code changes are approved, my remote branch is then merged into remote master.

Does this sound right?

After trying to sync a commit I get the error message: "conflict prevents automatic merging" and the suggestion to "Next steps: Manually resolve these conflicts and push new changes to the source branch.".

How do I resolve the conflict in Visual Studio 2017.

As you can tell, I am new to Git and trying to find my footing. I know, lots of questions.

I am currently not using the Git command line in any way. Only Visual Studio 2017.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I personally like doing `git pull --rebase` instead of a plain old `git pull`.

Comment: You need to manually go through the regions of conflict and correct them to what you think is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that master is the branch from which you have checked your branch out of and is the branch where all PR changes are merged into.

Lets assume the master branch has been changed since development because of pull requests being approved. First, checkout into master and then pull in recent changes.

```
git checkout master 
git pull
git checkout [Your Branch Name]
```

Now that you are on your branch again, you should do a rebase. You can do many things with a rebase- but the main uses are to squash commits into a single one (so you don't have 12 commits that are saying things like "minor change"), and you pick all the commits you want to use. Since you're new to git- you probably want to pick all of them- but if you ever want to know how to pick only certain commits- this is how! Read more about git rebase here:

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history

Let's do a rebase,

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Depending on how things are set up on your machine, something in your terminal or editor should pop up which will let you pick your commits. Assuming you want all your commits for the pull request- type "pick" next to each commit and save the file and exit. The rebase will run and will stop if you have any conflicts (if you worked on the same file as another developer you're bound to run into some conflicts). You can run the following command to see where conflicts are

```
git status
```

Most text editors will highlight the areas in the files to show where the conflicts are. You will either have to pick your code, the other developers code, or find a way to change it to what you think it should be like and do this for ALL conflicts. Once you are done with the conflicts so far, add the changes

```
git add .
```

Then continue the rebase

```
git rebase --continue
```

Repeat this process until it says the rebase is complete. Test your code and make sure everything looks right. Seriously. Make sure everything is working as intended. If it is- we can now push are changes to our feature branch

```
git push origin [Your-Branch-Name] --force
```

I won't go too much into detail about the force flag- just know that, as someone new to git, **never** use the flag unless you are doing a rebase (this is why it is super important to make sure everything is working before pushing). It will overwrite other changes which is why you should be careful using it in other circumstances.

Now if you check the history of commits

```
git log
```

You should see whichever commits you decided to pick (or just 1 if you decided to squash all of them in the rebase) AND you should see the commits the other developers made. Now you can open a pull request in github and after it is approved, merge your branch. You can use the UI on the website or look up how to do it in the terminal. Assuming you made no other changes you would be able to do

```
git checkout master 
git merge [Your-Branch-Name]
git push origin master
```

After all of this, your branch will be merged into master and all your changes will be on the master branch, and all conflicts with other developer changes will have been resolved.

While these are all command line commands, you should be able to do this using  a GUI or through other means- but I highly urge you to learn the command line for git as it will make things a lot easier, in my opinion. Most advice for git online will be using the command line. It can be daunting at first but once you reuse these commands they will become natural.

Let me know if you run into any issues or need additional help. This process should have answered all your questions, it is a very basic workflow for git for beginners.